# Vertical animated text rotation

Tags: css, css-animations

I need to create vertical animated text rotation for my homepage.

I found this very nice example. It uses the CSS property `transform: rotateX(0deg); rotateX(90deg);` etc.

But there are only four lines of text and I need 6 sentences. Any idea how to make same effect with more than 4 sentences?

```css
.home{
 width:100%;
}
.home:before{
 content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
.home h3{
 position:absolute;
 font-size:74px;
 text-align: left;
    color:#009393;
  margin-left:15%;
 font-weight:700;
}

.stage{
 width: auto;
 margin-top: 15px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .cubespinner{
 -webkit-animation-name:spincube;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 -webkit-animation-duration:8s;
 animation-name:spincube;

 animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 animation-duration:8s;
 -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
 -moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;
 -ms-transform-style:preserve-3d;
 transform-style:preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transform-origin:40px 40px 0;
 -moz-transform-origin:40px 40px 0;
 -ms-transform-origin:40px 40px 0;
 transform-origin:40px 40px  0;
  }
  .cubespinner div{
   position:absolute;
   width:400px;
   height:80px;
   text-align:left;
   color:#109393;
   font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;
   font-size:74px;
   font-weight:700;
   }
  .cubespinner .face1{
   color:#f1c40f;
   -webkit-transform:translateZ(40px);
   -moz-transform:translateZ(40px);
   -ms-transform:translateZ(40px);
   transform:translateZ(40px);
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   }
 .cubespinner .face2{
  color:#fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(40px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(40px);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(40px);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(40px);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 }
 .cubespinner .face3{
  color:#f85555;
  -webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg)  translateZ(40px);
  -moz-transform:rotateX(180deg)  translateZ(40px);
  -ms-transform:rotateX(180deg)  translateZ(40px);
  transform:rotateX(180deg)  translateZ(40px);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
 .cubespinner .face4{
  color:#fff;
  -webkit-transform:rotateX(270deg) translateZ(40px);
  -moz-transform:rotateX(270deg) translateZ(40px);
  -ms-transform:rotateX(270deg) translateZ(40px);
  transform:rotateX(270deg) translateZ(40px);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 }


/*Cubical Flipping or rotation*/
@-webkit-keyframes spincube {
    from,to  { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);}
    15%      { -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);}
    25%      { -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);}
    40%      { -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);}
    50%      { -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);}
    65%      { -webkit-transform: rotateX(270deg);}
 75%      { -webkit-transform: rotateX(270deg);}
 95%      { -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);}
 100%      { -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);}
  }@keyframes spincube {
    from,to {
   -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
      -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
      transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
    15% {
   -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
      -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg);
      transform: rotateX(90deg);
    }
 25% {
   -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
      -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg);
      transform: rotateX(90deg);
    }
 40% {
   -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
      -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
      transform: rotateX(180deg);
    }
 50% {
   -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
      -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
      transform: rotateX(180deg);
    }
    65% {
   -webkit-transform: rotateX(270deg);
      -moz-transform: rotateX(270deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateX(270deg);
      transform: rotateX(270deg);
    }
 75% {
   -webkit-transform: rotateX(270deg);
      -moz-transform: rotateX(270deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateX(270deg);
      transform: rotateX(270deg);
    }
 90% {
   -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);
      -moz-transform: rotateX(360deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateX(360deg);
      transform: rotateX(360deg);
    }
    100% {
   -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);
      -moz-transform: rotateX(360deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateX(360deg);
      transform: rotateX(360deg);
    }
```

```html
<div  class="home col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   <h3 id="resizing-h3" class="" >
     <span>
       <div class="stage">
        <div class="cubespinner">
         <div class="face1">Innovative</div>
         <div class="face2">Creative</div>
         <div class="face3">Unbeatable</div>
         <div class="face4">Exceptional</div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </span>
     </h3>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use of a blank sentence in 2 places**

I've attached a code.
It is simple, I just duplicated the div "cubespinner" and make 6 sentences, like you want.

It's a lightweight solution, not for any number of sentences, but it's enough for 6 :)

```css
.home{
 width:100%;
}
.home:before{
 content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
.home h3{
 position:absolute;
 font-size:74px;
 text-align: left;
    color:#009393;
  margin-left:15%;
 font-weight:700;
}

.stage{
 width: auto;
 margin-top: 15px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .cubespinner{
 animation-name:spincube;
 animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 animation-duration:12s;
 transform-style:preserve-3d;
 transform-origin:40px 40px  0;
  }
.cubespinner2{
 animation-name:spincube;
 animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 animation-duration:12s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
 transform-style:preserve-3d;
 transform-origin:40px 40px  0;
  }
  .cubespinner div, .cubespinner2 div{
   position:absolute;
   width:400px;
   height:80px;
   text-align:left;
   color:#109393;
   font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;
   font-size:74px;
   font-weight:700;
   }
  .cubespinner .face1, .cubespinner2 .face1{
   color:#f1c40f;
   transform:translateZ(40px);
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   }
 .cubespinner .face2, .cubespinner2 .face2{
  color:#fff;
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(40px);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 }
 .cubespinner .face3, .cubespinner2 .face3{
  color:#f85555;
  transform:rotateX(180deg)  translateZ(40px);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
 .cubespinner .face4, .cubespinner2 .face4{
     color:#f1c40f;
  transform:rotateX(270deg) translateZ(40px);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 }


/*Cubical Flipping or rotation*/
@-webkit-keyframes spincube {
   from,to  { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);}
    5%      { -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);}
    16%      { -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);}
    21%      { -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);}
    33%      { -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);}
    38%      { -webkit-transform: rotateX(270deg);}
 50%      { -webkit-transform: rotateX(270deg);}
 55%      { -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);}
 100%      { -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);}
  }
```

```html
<div  class="home col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   <h3 id="resizing-h3" class="" >
     <span>
       <div class="stage">
        <div class="cubespinner">
         <div class="face1"></div>
         <div class="face2">Creative</div>
         <div class="face3">Unbeatable</div>
         <div class="face4">Exceptional</div>
        </div>
                <div class="cubespinner2">
         <div class="face1"></div>
         <div class="face2">666666</div>
         <div class="face3">555555</div>
         <div class="face4">Innovative</div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </span>
     </h3>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! You are the best!