# Vertical animated text rotation for more than 4 lines

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions, text-rotation

I need to create vertical animated text rotation. I found this [Vertical animated text rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57446765/vertical-animated-text-rotation) But there are only four lines of text and I need 5 sentences. Any idea how to make same effect with more than 5 sentences?

```css
.mainBox {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.cubespinner {
  -webkit-animation-name: spincube;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-name: spincube;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 40px 40px 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 40px 40px 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 40px 40px 0;
  transform-origin: 40px 40px 0;
}

.cubespinner div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #109393;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 74px;
  font-weight: 700;
  /*background-color: black;*/
}

.cubespinner .face1 {
  /*color:#f1c40f;*/
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(40px);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(40px);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(40px);
  transform: translateZ(40px);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.cubespinner .face2 {
  /*color:#fff;*/
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(72deg) translateZ(40px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(72deg) translateZ(40px);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(72deg) translateZ(40px);
  transform: rotateX(72deg) translateZ(40px);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.cubespinner .face3 {
  /*color:#f85555;*/
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(144deg) translateZ(40px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(144deg) translateZ(40px);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(144deg) translateZ(40px);
  transform: rotateX(144deg) translateZ(40px);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.cubespinner .face4 {
  /*color:#fff;*/
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(216deg) translateZ(40px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(216deg) translateZ(40px);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(216deg) translateZ(40px);
  transform: rotateX(216deg) translateZ(40px);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.cubespinner .face5 {
  /*color:#fff;*/
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(270deg) translateZ(40px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(270deg) translateZ(40px);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(270deg) translateZ(40px);
  transform: rotateX(270deg) translateZ(40px);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}


/*Cubical Flipping or rotation*/

@-webkit-keyframes spincube {
  from,
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(72deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(72deg);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(144deg);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(144deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(216deg);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(216deg);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(270deg);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(270deg);
  }
  95% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spincube {
  from,
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(72deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(72deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(72deg);
    transform: rotateX(72deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(72deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(72deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(72deg);
    transform: rotateX(72deg);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(144deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(144deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(144deg);
    transform: rotateX(144deg);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(144deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(144deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(144deg);
    transform: rotateX(144deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(216deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(216deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(216deg);
    transform: rotateX(216deg);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(216deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(216deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(216deg);
    transform: rotateX(216deg);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(270deg);
    transform: rotateX(270deg);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(270deg);
    transform: rotateX(270deg);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(360deg);
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(360deg);
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cubespinner">
  <div class="face1">Innovative</div>
  <div class="face2">Creative</div>
  <div class="face3">Unbeatable</div>
  <div class="face4">Exceptional</div>
  <div class="face5">New</div>
</div>
```